# Android in-app purchases: full dev version

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm developing application in demo-full model (in-app purchase, which unlocks full features of application).

The information about license will be stored in internal storage in some JSON or SQLite - I don't care much about cracking, application mostly likely simply won't be worth cracking.

Obviously, I'd like to have full version on my mobile. How should I approach it?

- Making a backdoor, which turns on full version in production application is a very bad idea
- Putting license data into internal storage each time when I publish new version won't be comfortable
- Maintaining full-dev version without licensing will consume time and I'd rather spend that time on developing features
- Buy the app myself? :)

Maybe there's an option to make one-time promotion for myself? Or add a purchase manually? What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I found is that *developer cannot buy his own products on Google Play Store* for some reason. So option with promotions or even buying the inapp products is out of option (unless you use different account for development and for everyday usage).

The simplest way I found (which is not that much convenient, but the most convenient I could think of) is to define flavor (for instance "dev") and replace `LicenseService`, which provides information about user's purchases with one, which always returns `true` for all queries (effectively equals to user, who bought all possible options). I cannot update application on my mobile by the Google Play Store though - I build signed apk with that specific flavor and then install on the device manually (device asks, if I want to update the application without data loss).

```
public class LicenseService {

    public LicenseService(FilePathService filePathService, JsonLoaderService jsonLoaderService, EventBus eventBus) {

    }

    public boolean isFullVersion() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setFullVersion(boolean fullVersion) {
        // Ignore the call
    }
}
```

I still wait for better options if you know one.